# Selecting <option> from html using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I kind of got stuck with this code here. I am trying to retrieve the option text.

```
HTML code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() { 
     for(i=0; i<list.length; i++) { // assume list[i] contains different names
        var name_options = $('<option>' + list[i] + '</option>');
        $('#names').append(name_options);
     }

 /* I want to retrieve data when a particular option is selected. But this doesnt work*/
 $('#names').click(function(){
  var val = $(this).find(':selected').html();
 });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <select id='names' class='combobox'>
  !-- options for names go here --> 
 </select>
</body>
</html>
```

I was unable to retrieve the selected  value. And hence i used `$("#names")` as my selector since `$("#names option")` does not work. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `change()` handler and you can get the value directly from the `<select>` itself.

```
 $('#names').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
 });
```

During the selection process you will have several click events which is one reason `click()` won't be of much help

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#names option:selected").text();
```

or in your code

```
$(this).find(':selected').text();
```

Comment: A quik question, where is it recommended to use the "$(this).find(':selected').text();" ? After appending or before appending?

Comment: After. But as charlietfl pointed out, better use change event rather than click.